# Expresiones regulares con Python

Tags: python, regex, split

Estoy intentando hacer un split con python a través de una expresión regular. El caso es que quiero hacer un split por comas(","), pero no cuando tenga una coma y un espacio(", ").

Para ello estoy intentando lo siguiente:

```
rows.split(r',+[0-9A-Za-z]')
```

Con eso interpreto que lo que les estoy diciendo es que me haga un split cuando encuentre una coma seguida de cualquier caracter alfanumerico y no lo hace. A parte de esto, creo que tampoco es la solucion, pues el split me suprimiria el primer caracter que sigue la coma.

Alguien podría ayudarme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te dijeron en otra respuesta, el método split de una cadena **no** acepta regex. Para eso debes usar [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20split#re.split) del modulo re.

La regex que buscas sería esta:

```
,(?! )
```

Que se puede leer del siguiente modo:

- `,` coincide con una coma...
- `(?! )` si no está seguida de un espacio.

`[regex1](?![regex2])` nos dice que la regex completa coincide SOLO si regex1 coincide y no está seguida por regex2.

###### Demo

```
import re

cadena = "esto,es, una cadena,,separada con,  comas"

print(re.split(",(?! )", cadena))
```

###### Produce

```
['esto', 'es, una cadena', '', 'separada con,  comas']
```

#### Si quieres separar segun varias comas seguidas no seguida por un espacio...

Puedes usar la expresión

```
,+(?! )
```

El + dice "debe haber una o más ocurrencias de la regex anterior".

Comment: Gracias!! muy bien explicado, me han servido perfectamente las dos respuestas que me habéis dado!!

Answer (score 1):

Estás haciendo un split mediante una cadena, no una expresión regular. Para hacer un split con expresión regular debes usar la función [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20split#re.split). En este caso, casi la tienes, sería:

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r',+(?=[0-9A-Za-z])', 'foo,bar, baz,,qux')
['foo', 'bar, baz', 'qux']
```

La expresión regular significa:

- `,+` (cuando encuentre una o más comas)
- `(?=)` todo lo que encuentre en este grupo, pero no lo incluyas como parte del split
- `[0-9A-Za-z]` cualquier caracter alfanumérico

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación!!